# ONLY Build the latest commit in buildbot

Tags: git, buildbot

I have setup buildbot for my project with Git. I find that if I have several commits in my repository, the buildbot slaves will build and run all the changes instead of only the latest commit. Is there any method to set buildbot to only build my latest commit?

Thanks.

Comment: Try to config buildbot builds only git tags. Exmaple, v.****

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Merging Build Requests](http://docs.buildbot.net/current/manual/cfg-builders.html?highlight=mergerequests#id4) is the typical solution.

Comment: David, 1. when I add "c['collapseRequests'] = True" and "buildbot reconfig master", the log says, "Unknown BuildmasterConfig key collapseRequests"; or 2. When I add collapseRequests in BuilderConfig, using "c['builders'].append(BuilderConfig(..., collapseRequests=True))", error shows "__init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'collapseRequests' (traceback in logfile)". Do you have any suggestion? Thanks

Comment: Sorry, I sent you to the bleeding edge. In released builds, the correct parameter is 'mergeRequests' I've edited the answer above.